# Using translateY() to move hidden element without blank space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to create an animation to show a certain section when user clicks on an element. The section stays hidden (`translateY(-700px)`) when the page loads. Click event changes toggles the class `._active` Using transition on `margin-bottom` property results in low FPS count on the animation.

Question: 
Is there a way to animate this section without leaving the blank space when it's hidden?

SASS code for the section below

```
.section {
  padding: 50px 0 20px 0;
  background-color: black;
  display: block;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: translateY(-700px);
  transition: transform 1s;

  &._active {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Not using `translate`. It's an entirely **visual** effect. The element isn't *actually* moving...it just looks like it. You probably want negative margins. A [mcve] would be useful.

Comment: See - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/IuLfJ

Comment: If you want to stick with translate, one option could be to also transition the height property: https://jsfiddle.net/u3na98n8/

Comment: I tried both negative margins and height property - the problem is that this causes a very low framerate on an animation (I need to move other sections with a lot of content at the same time). I tried using jQuery animations, and CSS transitions - the effect is the same :)

Answer (score 1):

While you use `translate`, browser remembers an actual size of styled element. If you can remove `padding`, one option to approach it is transitioning `height` along with `translateY`:

```js
var toggler = document.getElementById("toggler");
var toggled = document.getElementById("toggled");

toggler.addEventListener("click", e => {
  toggled.classList.toggle('_active');
})
```

```css
.section {
  /* padding: 50px 0 20px 0; */
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  transform: translateY(-700px);  
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-700px);
  transition: transform 1s, height 1s;
  -webkit-transition: transform 1s, height 1s;
}
.section._active {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
    margin-bottom: 0;
    height: 130px; /* adjust for your section content */
}
```

```html
<button id="toggler">Toggle visibility</button>

<section id="toggled" class="section"></section>

<section>
    <p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit ametLorem ipsum dolor sit amet
  </p>
</section>
```

If you are going to have any content inside your section, one hack to *pad* it is using `border` with same color as section background, combined with adjusting the `height` property in your `_active` class.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I figured it out.

Using both `height` and `margin-bottom` properties result in a choppy animation. The only way (that I came across in that situation) is to use `transform: translateY()` on all elements that have to be moved with the element to show.

So I added another class to every section on a web page and changed it's `transform` property. This way I achieved a smooth animation that I wanted :). Please tell me if there's a better way to do it!

```js
$('#panel').on('click', function() {
  $('.new-class').toggleClass('down');
  $('.advanced-search').toggleClass('_active');
});
```

```css
.hero {
  height: 700px;
  background-color:  #FFD400;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}

#panel {
 width: 100%;
 color: white;
 background: #2E294E;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 30px 0;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 2;
}

.advanced-search {
 height: 700px;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 background: #D90368;
 text-align: center;
 margin-bottom: -700px;
 transform: translateY(-700px);
 transition: transform 1s;
}

.new-class {
 background-color: #F1E9DA;
 height: 300px;
 width: 100%;
 border: 1px solid white;
 text-align: center;
 font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
 transition: transform 1s;
}

.new-class.down {
  transform: translateY(700px);
}

.advanced-search._active {
  transform: translateY(0px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero"></div>
<div id="panel"> Click to show </div>
<div class="advanced-search"></div>
<div class="new-class">
  Some content
</div>
<div class="new-class">
  Some content
</div>
<div class="new-class">
  Some content
</div>
<div class="new-class">
  Some content
</div>
<div class="new-class">
  Some content
</div>
<div class="new-class">
  Some content
</div>
```